# insert fields from database1 into table from database2

Tags: mysql, insert, copy

I am using prestashop and have data in zencart I am matching up information and want to select the data to be inserted into a different table under different fields.

```
insert into presta_table1 (c1, c2, ...)
select c1, c2, ...
from zen_table1`
```

Since a lot is different I need to do approximately 800 records once I match up what field is what in what table.

I recently found a example

```
USE datab1;INSERT INTO datab3.prestatable (author,editor) 
SELECT author_name,editor_name FROM author,datab2.editor 
WHERE author.editor_id = datab2.editor.editor_id;
```

be nice to find a way to import avoiding duplicates

I am unable to find examples of this.

Comment: Prestashop has a great openness to it that allows all sorts of csv inputs. I was able to get the products and customers entered with some commands and mysqlworkbench

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get data out of this POS (Point of sale) system that uses mysql for a database.

I found tables with the data I needed and I exported the data out that came out in a csv format. I used calc in Libreoffice to open and then in anouther sheet manipulate the data into the example csv feilds and that worked good.

I had some issues with some of the data but I used consol commands to help me get by these let me share them with you.

Zencart description data exported from mysqlworkbench had some model numbers I needed to export out into there own field

> 43,1,"Black triple SS","Black Triple SS
>   
>   
>   12101-57 (7.5 inch)",,0

i used a command to add in " , " in so I could extract the data and over lay it . essential copy past into the spreadsheet Calc where I needed it in the normal order.

this sed command removes the ),(  in the file and replaces with a carriage return
I did a database dump and removed starting ( and ending ) then saved as zencart_product.csv then ran this in a console

> sed 's/),(/\n/g' zencart_product.csv > zencart_productNEW.csv

I had about 1000 files with $ and # in them so I put them all in a dir and renamed  them with

get rid of the $ symbol

> rename 's/\$//g' *

get rid of the $ symbol

> rename 's/\$//g' *

get rid of space

> rename "s/\s+//g" *

I hope people stuck in some software that want the data out are able to get it out with some time and effort and that this helps someone. Thanks